# sed for print two different word alernatively

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a requirement to print two different words in alternative white spaces in the file.

For example,

```
ABCD
EFGH
IGKL
MNOP
```

The above scenario, I want print ab and /ab alternatively like below:

```
ab
ABCD
/ab
ab
EFGH
/ab
ab
IGKL
/ab
ab
MNOP
/ab
```

*I want this one by one in a line by line format(Not horizontal format).*I know `sed 's|^[[:blank:]]*$|</ab>|'` this command is almost near to my case. But I don't know how to apply this. Please, someone, help me.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts and samples, also please use CODE TAGS `{}` button to wrap up them for better understanding.

Comment: Do you mean to wrap the lines into `<ab>`/`</ab>` tags? Or really `ab`/`/ab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` then following may help you here.

```
awk -v start="ab" -v end="/ab" '{print start ORS $0 ORS end}' Input_file
```

In case you need to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code too.

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please mention the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 2):

With gnu sed

```
sed -e 'i\ab' -e 'a\/ab' infile
```

---

How this work ?

On each line

first insert ab before with `'i\ab'`

next append /ab after with `'a\/ab'`

You must use 2 separates commands with `'-e'` to do that.

You can't use `sed 'i\ab;a\/ab'` because the first command i (insert) don't know where end the text to insert and get all the line.

So the inserted text is `ab;a/ab` before each line.

Another way to do that with all sed is

```
sed -e 'i\
    ab
    a\
    /ab' infile
```

Comment: very nice! Could you add some explanation for why this works and why it is different from `sed 'i\ab;a\/ab`